# NodeJs code binding in Java

Tags: javascript, java, binding

How could I make java bindings for nodejs code? For example, I would like to bind a library on npm in java. It's kinda like dll binding using JNA.

Comment: Use [Nashorn](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html). Or, you have to write some kind of JNA binding to **v8**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch There is JNA binding for V8 but not universal, its separated for diffrent OS. And could you listen for method execution and stuff with nashorn? (Executed via ScriptEngine)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by listening for method execution; that doesn't parse for me. What kind of binding are you trying to achieve? What kind of code is this library? At the very least, can you not write a nodejs rest server and then consume that from Java?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i am trying to bind node-minecraft-protocol in java, and i don't know stuff about node rest server

Comment: Please add some code or researches that you have even done before posting this question.